# trace inequality $|tr(XY)| \leq tr(|XY|)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, proof-verification, functional-calculus

Why does $|tr(XY)|  \leq tr(|XY|)$ hold for any complex matrices where $|XY|$ denotes $\sqrt{Y^*X^*XY}$?

would following proof be correct? So the trace of a matrix $A$ is the sum of its eigenvalues and the the trace of $|A|$ is the sum of the singular values:
$$|tr(A)|=|\sum \lambda_j|\leq \sum s_j=tr(|A|) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you consider $XY$ since $X$ and $Y$ always occur in
the combination $XY$. Thus setting $Z=XY$ you are asking why
$$|\operatorname{tr}Z|\leqslant\operatorname{tr}|Z|\,.$$
It often happens that one can write
$$Z=U|Z|,\;|Z|=\sqrt{Z^\ast\!Z}$$
where $U$ is a partial isometry. This is the case for closed densely defined
operators in Hilbert space, so applicable to your case
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition, T.Kato: "Perturbation
theory of linear operators", see polar decomposition of a closed operator)
Then
$$|\operatorname{tr}Z|=|\operatorname{tr}(U|Z|)|\leqslant \|U\|\, \operatorname{tr}|Z|\leqslant\operatorname{tr}|Z|$$
where $\|U\|$ is the operator norm of $U$. $U$ being a
partial isometry, $\|U\|\leqslant 1$.

Example
$$Z =
\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
 ,\;Z^\ast Z=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\0 & 0\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \\[3ex]
\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
 =
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
 ,\;U=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @ urgje Thanks yes you are right I should just have written $Z$. So in the finite dimensional case $U$ would be unitary.  Would following deduction be correct? $\|U\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Ux\|=\sup_{\|U^*x\|=1} \|UU^*x\|=\sup_{\|U^*x\|} \|x\|$ because $U^*$ is surjective? Can one follow from this that $\|U\| \leq 1$?

Comment: No, even in the finite-dimensional case $U$ need not be unitary. It is easy to find a $2x2$ counterexample where $U_{11}=1$, the other components being 0, so $U$ is a one-dimensional projection operator. Or even simpler, take this $U$ and multiply it with a Hermitean $2x2$-matrix to obtain $Z$. Thus your equality breaks down.

Comment: Ok so how does one get $\|U\| \leq 1$ then? I was actually pretty sure that the polar decomposition requires $U$ to be unitary as it is written in your link o.O

Comment: I added an example. As to your question, I am quite certain that  in Kato's book this matter is handled.

Comment: The polar decomposition claims the existence of a unitary matrix $U$ and a positive matrix $P$ such that $Z=UP$ your counter example only shows that there are also other possibilities to achieve this I think. But thanks for the answer it already helped me a lot.

Comment: I checked with Kato's book. His approach gives precisely what I thought to remember. It seems that different definitions of polar decomposition exist. But the one I employed gives precisely the result you were after.

Comment: Alright thanks man !